# Centos Email Server Unable to Send Email

Tags: centos, email, postfix, sendmail, smtp

I have a Centos 5 box.  My server is running plesk.  Individual domains are able to receive emails on plesk created email accounts.  However, my server is not able to send emails.  I tried to use php sendmail and linux mutt command, none of them allows outgoing email.  In the plesk panel, I see all emails queued.  I also notice the PHP mail function is not sending emails either.

In its firewall iptables I have enabled ports 25 and 587 for smtp.

I have MX 0 and 10 for godaddy's  smtp.secureserver.net
per https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#MX/

I am really confused why I am able to receive email in my server box but enable to send any email out.

Comment: what does `mailq` and the mail logs show as going on?

Comment: @thrig how do I find out with mailq? Does Centos 5 uses sendmail or postfix?  where is the logs by the way?

Comment: @thrig how do I find out my email client is sendmail for postfix?

Comment: `rpm -qf /usr/sbin/sendmail` and then for Sendmail `mail; mailq -Ac` or for Postfix `mailq`; logs in either case should be in `/var/log/maillog` or rotations thereof